# Checking if logged-in user is author of an entity that is currently being viewed

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, cookies, authorization, app-engine-ndb

I'd like to check if the currently logged in user is the 'author' of the entity that is currently being viewed.

Here's what I've got:

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

When logging in, a cookie name 'user_id' is set to a value equal to the ID of an `Account` entity. The user_id cookie would look like this:

```
"user_id=5629499534213120"
```

Therefore, once a user_id cookie exists, and its value is equal to an Account entity's ID in the datastore, a user is *logged in*.

Now we have the BlogPost:

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty() #This value is set to the user_id of the currently logged in user
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

Now, a BlogPost entity can be found in this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/blogpost/<blogpost entity's id>
Example: http://www.example.com/blogpost/8234086234786238649236423
```

I'd like to create an `is_author()` function:

```
def is_author():
    # Gets the url argument of the entity currently being viewed.
    # Compares it to the user_id cookie of the currently logged in user.
    # If they match, then the currently user is the author of the blogpost being viewed.
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_author(blogpostid, account):    
    if BlogPost.query(ndb.And(BlogPost.id=blogpostid, BlogPost.author_key == account.key)).get():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then to use it:

```
#get the account object based on your cookie
account = Account.get_by_id(self.request.cookies["user_id"])

#get your blog post id
blogpostid = "12341234214"


#check if it's the author
if is_author(blogpostid, account):
    do_whatever()
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the blogpost id from the URL, just pass it in as a parameter.  For example:

```
class BlogPostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, blogpostid):
       #you can use the blogpostid variable here now.

...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blogpost/(.*)', BlogPostHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Garett. It cleared a lot of things up. One issue though. In your example, it seems like we must manually enter the `blogpostid`. Id there any way we can use a function to grab the blogpostid from any blogpost page we visit?